# How are CPU Register values updated?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-registers

I know this might be a silly question which I am asking, but I am really curious about this, since I am not having much knowledge of computer architecture.
Suppose I have a Register R1 and say I loaded value of a variable say LOCK=5 into the register, so now R1 has the value 5 stored into it, now let's suppose I updated the value of LOCK to 10 after some time, so will the value of register still be 5 or will it be updated.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to register based CPU architectures, I think Neo from the matrix has a valueable lession: "There are no variables."

Variables, as you're using them in a higher level programming languages are an abstract thing for describing to the compiler what operations to do a particular piece of data. That data may reside in system memory, or for temporary values never leave the register file.

However once the program has been compiled to a binary, there no longer are variables! For debugging purposes the compiler may annotate the code with information of the kind "at this particular position in the code, what is referred to as variable 'x' right now happens to be held in …".

I think the best way to understand this is to compile some very simple programs and look at their respective assembly, to see how things fit together. The [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) is a really valuable tool, here.